# Why does for loop quit after calling another method?

Tags: for-loop, methods, while-loop, java.util.scanner, nested-loops

I am trying to fill a matrix with data read from a text file. The matrix is simply a 2D array that has already been created with parameters. I have check and the array is being created to the correct size based on parameters. For some reason when I scan the next value (value) and then try to insert it at a certain point in the array it is successful once and then quits without filling the rest of the array. If the insertAt method is removed than the loops work perfectly going through all the needed cells. For some reason when the method is added and called it works fine for the first cell but then quits after that.

While loop that inserts the value at a specific point.

```
while(scan.hasNext()) {
    for(int i = 0; i < m1.row; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m1.column; j++) {
            value = scan.nextInt();
            m1.insertAt(i, j, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Method for matrix that control the insertion of the value.

```
public void insertAt(int row, int column, int value) {
    if(row >= 0 && column >= 0) {
        matrix[row][column] = value;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error inserting value. Row: " + row + " Column: " + column);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger to determine where it drops out?

Comment: I have, the debugger goes all the way to the first cell (0,0) the loops increase to (0,1) and then it just quits.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered it does this because you cannot put a variable in at a specific point at one time, even if you try to put them in in order. If the matrix is initialized and filled with 0's or some other digit it works fine. It has to be filled creating an empty matrix with a specific size does not work. Otherwise you have to restart the entire method each time to add 1 variable.